# Changing CSS of Parent Element Based Upon Value of Child Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to change the visibility of the second div with the class `.form-group`. Using jQuery I am trying to grab the value of the selected option and then based upon that value change the aforementioned visibility.

If the value is 0 then the second `div .form-group` should become visible. I am having difficulties with this, I have tried `parents()` and `closest()`, however, I believe I have been implementing these incorrectly

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required" for="userQuestions[1]">Do you have any dietary requirements? <span class="required">*</span></label><select class="form-control user-success" id="userQuestions_1" name="userQuestions[1]" required="required">
        <option value="">
            Please select
        </option>
        <option value="0">
            Yes
        </option>
        <option value="1">
            No
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="userQuestions[2]">Would you like to stay for after conference drinks?</label><select class="form-control" id="userQuestions_2" name="userQuestions[2]">
        <option value="">
            Please select
        </option>
        <option value="0">
            Yes
        </option>
        <option value="1">
            No
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#useQuestion[1]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '0'){ 
        $('.form-group:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.form-group:nth-of-type(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.visible {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: your jquery selector is wrong. The id for that select is `#userQuestions_1`, so use `$('#userQuestions_1').on('change',function() {});` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgZRoy

Comment: You have a typo in the jQuery selector. `$('#useQuestion[1]')` should be `$('#userQuestion[1]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function replace this `('#useQuestion[1]')` to `('#userQuestions_1')`

I just modified your code check here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userQuestions_1').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == '0'){ 
        $('.form-group:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

```css
.form-group:nth-of-type(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.visible {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required" for="userQuestions[1]">Do you have any dietary requirements? <span class="required">*</span></label><select class="form-control user-success" id="userQuestions_1" name="userQuestions[1]" required="required">
        <option value="">
            Please select
        </option>
        <option value="0">
            Yes
        </option>
        <option value="1">
            No
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="userQuestions[2]">Would you like to stay for after conference drinks?</label><select class="form-control" id="userQuestions_2" name="userQuestions[2]">
        <option value="">
            Please select
        </option>
        <option value="0">
            Yes
        </option>
        <option value="1">
            No
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just gave it a go, worked great, thank you very much!